# Coldfusion - getting 5 years in the past and inserting into select

Tags: select, coldfusion

I am trying to get the past 5 years from 2011 into a `<cfselect>` (or select tag) and outout them as options. This is my current solution...

```
<cfset dtStart = #year(now())# />
<cfset dtToday = dtStart />

<select name="date">
    <cfloop index="intDayOffset" from="0" to="4" step="1">
        <cfset date = (#dtToday#-#intDayOffset#) />
        <cfoutput><option value="#date#">#date#</option></cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

Can anyone come up with a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simplifies it a bit

```
<cfloop index="date" from="#dtToday#" to="#dtToday - 5#" step="-1">
    <cfoutput><option value="#date#">#date#</option></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfloop from="#year(now())#" to="#year(now())-5#" index="y" step="-1">

#y#

</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you compared CF to PHP as though readability and terseness were important, I thought I'd throw out what your solution would look like in Ruby + [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/):

```
- year = Date.today.year
%select{name:'date'}
  - (0..4).each do |offset|
    - date = year - offset
    %option{value:date}= date
```

*(Feel free to vote this answer down, as it does not answer the question directly. I'm not trying to convince you that CF is bad or that Haml is better, just showing you an alternative.)*

Comment: Always interesting to see how other languages handle things.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would handle it.

```
<select name="date">
    <cfloop index="intDayOffset" from="0" to="4" step="1">
        <cfoutput>
            <option value="#year(dateAdd('yyyy',-intDayOffset, now()))#">#year(dateAdd('yyyy',-intDayOffset, now()))#</option>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```